# Why is this C# date comparison with SQL datetime not returning results?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I know that records exist between this date range in SQL, but I have tried various formats and even made the range much larger and this still does not return results. What am I doing incorrectly in this query that is causing no records to be returned? Thanks for the help.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
DateTime yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string yesterdayString = yesterday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
string tomorrowString = tomorrow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

int itemNum = 0;
string query = "select DocID, CNo, DocType, DocNumber from errordata where cno = '" + cno + "' and createddate > '" + yesterdayString + "' and createddate < '" + tomorrowString + "' order by '" + sorton + "'desc";
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: because you should use parameters in your query

Comment: perhaps you are not getting results because you are also filtering on "CNO" and that statement isn't true?

Comment: Aren't you getting exceptions because of the invalid sql ?

Comment: Sorry to say I had removed some of the code including several rows that were being selected. I accidentally removed the from portion, however, the query itself still had from included. I have tried adding the parameters, but it is still not returning any records. I tested the same query in SQL and it works, it's just a matter of something with the C# dates I am assuming.

Comment: Have you checked that yesterdayString and tomorrowString contains exactly what you expect, and that "cno" is indeed a char/varchar/nvarchar datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
string query = "SELECT DocID, CNo, DocType, DocNumber "+
               "FROM tableName "+
               "WHERE cno = @cno AND "+
               "CreatedDate BETWEEN @yesterday AND @tomorrow";

var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connectionString);

sql.Parameters.Add("@cno", cno);
sql.Parameters.Add("@yesterday", yesterday);
sql.Parameters.Add("@tomorrow", tomorrow);
```

I think that your problem is the missing `FROM`. Furthermore, I wrote your query using parameters, which prevents sql injections.

Answer (score 4):

the query you are creating is missing the FROM clause.  I would expect you are getting an exception.

Comment: the only answer that answered the actual question (not that the parts about parameters are not important)

Comment: not likely. if the date formatting is not correct you don't get results, if the from clause is missing the expected result is an exception. Nevertheless , good catch to see the from clause is missing.

Comment: yeah, aside from the FROM clause this is valid T-SQL.  I don't know how much work the poster did to boil his problem down to something easy to digest.

Comment: Well, using parameters is a "best practice" etc., it doesn't make his query invalid

Comment: It does make sure you don't get results with this date thing, who on earth knows how to format a date in a string that sql server understands.

Comment: It's just funny - most of us were far too busy correcting his non-use of parameters to notice the most obvious flaw in the query (myself included) :) I agree with the "using parameters" answers too, of course.

Answer (score 3):

If you use parameterized queries you will not have this problem.
See : http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06

your query should look like this :

```
@"SELECT VALUE Contact FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Contacts 
            AS Contact WHERE Contact.LastName = @ln" ;
```

notice the @ placeholder for the parameters
then you can do this :

```
// 2. define parameters used in command object
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@City";
param.Value         = inputCity;

// 3. add new parameter to command object
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

// get data stream
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

but the parameter value can be a normal DateTime Value like say DateTime.Today.
this should get you started.

Also check the exceptions you might get. Invalid sql will throw exceptions. Catch them and correct the sql if needed.